# convert gtkglade to libglade for a backwards compatibility

Tags: python, pygtk, backwards-compatibility, glade, gtkbuilder

I have a python gtk app that I am porting to an environment that can only use pygtk2.10. pygtk2.10 doesn't not use the gtkbuilder infrastructure but rather the libglade infrastructure I have a 2 goals

1) convert the gtkbuilder glade file format to libglade format. Basically I want to do the opposite of gtk-builder-convert (which converts libglade to gtkbuilder formats as far as I understand it)

2) find a mapping between gtk.builder functions and libglade functions to be functionally the same

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

To solve #1, you can still save Libglade files in Glade. There is a control at the bottom of the Save dialog where you can select Libglade or GtkBuilder.

To solve #2, I suggest you read the documentation of [gtk.Builder](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkbuilder.html) and [gtk.glade.XML](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gladexml.html) and find out what is appropriate to the way you use each one in your application.